# rails and mongodb - .and() with nested .in() queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, user-input, querying

I'm trying to search through mongoDB via user input.
Options for a user would be 'AND' & 'OR'. 
The 'and' functionality is not working the way I need to.
Right now if a user searches for "foo AND bar", then I split it into an array `["foo", "bar"]`. I then want to search through all fields in my database for any document that has 'foo' and 'bar'. 
This is my query, `@q` is the search array:

`@item = Item.and( {:food.in => @q}), {:clothes.in => @q}, {:movies.in => @q} )`

Right now this is searching for "foo" AND "bar" to BOTH be in the same field food, clothes and movies instead of just both in the same document. So it returns 0 even when 'foo' is in food and 'bar' is in movies.

How can I properly nest an `.any_of()` condition or any other condition inside an `.and()` so that it searches for both words in the *whole* document not each individual field? 

Thanks in advance for any help, I've been at this for a while..

**EDIT**

For a little more clairty, I would like to search a WHOLE mongoDB document for multiple words, not each and every field in the document... which is what the above query does.
Does anyone know how to do this??

Comment: Solved it finally.. if anyone wants to know how to get this working view my other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507610/rails-mongoid-merging-multiple-criteria/33507611#33507611